# Having problems with tkinter destroy method with labels

Tags: python, tkinter

First time posting to Stack! I am very new to Python / Tkinter so bear with me.

I am trying to write code that looks for a saved txt file upon startup that describes the path of a chosen XML file, and for it to print a tkinter label based on the chosen directory.

Problem I'm having is this: if you choose the XML file path, it will print the path - which is what I want. But, if you choose another XML file path, the previously printed label doesn't get destroyed, and the new label gets applied on top of the old one. I have looked at other people having similar issues and I'm stuck. I have tried a few different ways of implementing the `.destroy()` method, and none of them seem to be working. I wouldn't be surprised if there are other errors/redundancies in my code **(please focus on the `.destroy()` issue)**, but it seems to be working the way I want other than this issue. I do not get any error messages with this code.

Here's what the code looks like right now (I only posted the part that is having the issue, let me know if you need more).

I have been testing this issue by selecting a long file path first, and then a shorter path on the desktop. The path on the desktop will print on top of the previous label instead destroying the previous label, seemingly ignoring the reset() function.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk() 
 
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 750, height = 750)
canvas1.pack()

#Destroy previous label
global label_file
def reset():
    label_file.destroy()

#Function that saves selected path
def findfile():
    reset()
    global file_selected
    file_selected = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("XML Files", "*.xml")])
    if file_selected == "":
        label_file = tk.Label(root, text= 'Error. Choose location of config.xml:', bg='red' )
        canvas1.create_window(370, 165, window=label_file)
    else:
        label_file = tk.Label(root, text= 'Saved Path: '+ file_selected, bg='yellow' )
        canvas1.create_window(370, 165, window=label_file)
        savedpath = open("path.txt", "w")
        savedpath.write(file_selected)
        
#Attempts to read save file on startup
try:
    with open('path.txt', 'r') as f:
        global file_selected
        file_selected = f.readline()   
        label_file = tk.Label(root, text= 'Path: ' + file_selected, bg='#00ff00' )
        canvas1.create_window(370, 165, window=label_file)
        button1 = tk.Button (root, text='Change Path',command=findfile, bg='orange')
        canvas1.create_window(50, 200, window=button1)
        
#If no save file on startup
except FileNotFoundError:
    file_selected = ""
    label_file = tk.Label(root, text= 'Choose location of config.xml file: ', bg='red' )
    canvas1.create_window(168, 165, window=label_file)
    button2 = tk.Button (root, text='Browse',command=findfile, bg='orange') 
    canvas1.create_window(50, 200, window=button2) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you share your error with us ? We do need to guess these informations now.

Comment: I do not get any error messages. If you choose a directory path for the XML file, it will print the path. Then, if you choose another directory path, it will print the new path on top of the old label, instead of destroying the old label.

Comment: `labe_file` inside of `findfile` is a local variable.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you!!!!!!!!!! oh my gosh how did I miss that. Got it working.

Comment: Why destroy the label in the first place? Just change it's `text` option.